# RegEx to fix <div>s inside <p>s

Tags: html, regex

I need to fix invalid html (DIVs inside Ps). I'm trying to find a regexp to fix it, but I cant. The regex must replace `<DIV>...</DIV>` inside Ps with `</p><DIV>...</DIV><p>`, but not the DIVs outside Ps.

something like (PSEUDOEXPRESSION):

```
s/(<p>)(NOT_</p>*)(<div>.*?</div>)/$1$2</p>$3<p>/
```

Here is the initial html (wrong):

```
<p>
  text 1
  <div>inside div 1</div>
  <div>inside div 2</div>
  text 2
</p>
text 3
<div>inside div 3</div>
text 4
<p>
  text 5
  <div>inside div 4</div>
  text 6
</p>
```

and here is how it should be:

```
<p>
  text 1
  </p><div>inside div 1</div><p>
  </p><div>inside div 2</div><p>
  text 2
</p>
text 3
<div>inside div 3</div>
text 4
<p>
  text 5
  </p><div>inside div 4</div><p>
  text 6
</p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I'm trying to find a regexp to fix it, but I cant."* - And you should stop looking for one. Regex is not capable of dealing with HTML properly. There are tools that fix HTML for you, like [tidy](https://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/). Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Tomalak I know, but this is part of a CMS with realtime page generation, so I need something as fas as a regexp.

Comment: When I wrote *"Regex is not capable of dealing with HTML properly."* I meant it like that.

Comment: If this is a PHP-based CMS: Tidy is bundled with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Comment: Surely, the answer is to cease to generate invalid html, rather than come up with a solution for continuing to repair it's invalid output? Tricks like the one you propose are the reason why software gets slower with increased hardware abilities. You know what the right answer is....

Comment: I know that I must create valid HTML, but all this mess comes from a old CMS migration.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will work in a PCRE style regex.
Like the one used in PHP or Notepad++.

```regex
(?:<p>|\G)[^<>]*?\K(<div>.*?<\/div>)|<\/p>\K(?R)
```

Replace by : `<p>\1</p>`

Can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/uI6rW0/2)